# Call stack window always empty

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2005, callstack

After being introduced to the call stack window by [this ASP.NET MVC video](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/matthijs/aspnet-mvc-2-basics-introduction-by-scott-hanselman) I've attempted to understand how it works.

My understanding was that it shows all of the method calls - in the order they were called.  However its always blank whilst I'm debugging - am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ahh - As is usually the case once I've asked a question I work it out!

Its turns out it is **only shown when a breakpoint has been hit**

Comment: Or when you have pressed the pause button.  Showing the call stack while the application is running would mean that the call stack would be updated millions of times every second.  Therefore, you have to explicitly halt the application (by pausing it or by using a breakpoint).

Comment: @Patrick - I understand many thanks.  However I can't get my head round why the call stack isn't showing will the program is running normally - I'm sure it isn't 'millions of times a second' but only each time a method is called

Comment: Using Process Explorer (www.sysinternals.com) you can see the call stack from a running process (double click process, choose thread, double click thread), but it is still a snapshot of the current call stack.  But possibly it could help you in your case.

Comment: in my case i kept breakpoint  very fist function inside main , still i am not able to get any callstack..... even the code is building properly