# Trace a code flow in VIsual Studio

Tags: visual-c++

We have our C++ project codebase developed in VC++ IDE. I can compile and run the same.

The executable covers a lot of scenarios and flow executions. Is there a way by which during a flow execution - the VC++ Studio can tell us which are the methods the flow entered or trace the flow.

Assume that 3 functions are called out of 10 during a flow execution. Can we get a trace stating the 3 functions entered during execution in order?

Answer (score 1):

In **Visual Studio 2015(+)**, there is a '**Call Stack**' window that can be used to do exactly what you are describing. With that being said, it still does require you to place at least one break-point somewhere. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690332/call-stack-window-always-empty) for more information.

So what you can do is **launch the application**, then from Visual Studio click **Debug** > **Windows** > **Call Stack**. Unfortunately this window will remain empty until you designate a break-point somewhere in your script - somewhat frustrating. However the Call Stack window does provide more information than simply placing breakpoints in code and performing manual tracing.

Hopefully this information will help your project!

Comment: Yes I am aware of debugging tools in VC but tracing is different. Say I am working on a flow enhancement and codebase is spread across thousands of line - if I can trace the flow I would 100 times speed up the development work that start debugging from main(). Further since there are threads and asynchronous events debugging such a flow will quiet be a challange

Comment: I see what you're saying, so you mean like a method logger/tracer without having to stop immediately and then wait to find it.

Comment: Okay I did some more research and tested another window on my C# project I edited my answer and perhaps it will help your development team. Good luck!